# Bar Graph in jFreeChart w bars all start from a specific range

Tags: java, bar-chart, jfreechart

Is it possible to generate a bar graph in jFreeChart where bars all start around a particular value instead of the zero axis? Our team has interest in this view.

Here is an example where the default behavior has the bars all between the value and the origin. We want the bars to be between the value and the mean (average).

[image]

I suppose a workaround is we calculate the offset from the mean and plot them in respect to the origin and then hide the axis but then we are not able to show the axis to our users.

Comment: Can you adjust the range for the axis, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36944687/230513)?

Comment: Range should be roughly around the mean. I did assume that I can define the origin as the mean and calculate the displacement from the mean and plot those to get the visual effect they wanted. We would just rename the graph to be "distance from mean" as opposed to exposure level. I think that is a feasible solution and I might not need an answer to this question.

Comment: @trashgod Do you know if it is possible to adjust all the tick units on the scale to be offset by a constant amount in jFree? I was thinking I could just add the mean to the scale on the answer I am trying below and that would basically get me the original solution my team has requested.

Comment: AFAIK, the scaling is pure liner interpolation between model (data) and view (plot); IIUC, the approach you outline below changes the range values accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having bar graphs stop at another value besides the origin we are just redefining the graph axis origin to be at the mean and offsetting everything. So instead of something like exposure level we now call the value axis distance from aggregate mean. Not exactly what I was originally looking in the OP but a cleaner solution overall. We'll let the user toggle between the two modes.

[image]

Comment: Some toggle examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20JCheckBox).